# Angular module calls wrong route. Routing problem

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an app with some modules and routes hierarchy.
Just after registration, user goes to "boarding" module, which has it's own hierarchy of routes.

For example, routes should look like this

```
"appdomain/#/onboarding/greeting" (this is the first step)
"appdomain/#/onboarding/strategies"
"appdomain/#/onboarding/object/incomesCreation"
"appdomain/#/onboarding/object/editIncomes/:id"
```

After the boarding is done, the user goes to another part of application, which has couple of modules

```
IncomesModule
ExpensesModule
```

and routing for these modules:

```
"appdomain/#/expenses/createBudget"
"appdomain/#/expenses/1234"  (here goes the ID of object)

"appdomain/#/incomes/create"
"appdomain/#/incomes/1234" (here goes the ID of object)
```

The "boarding" modules needs to use some components from expenses and incomes modules.

For example, *"appdomain/#/onboarding/object/editIncomes/1234"* and *"appdomain/#/incomes/1234"* should show the same component (FreeBalanceEditPageComponent), but in different wrappers.
For that purpose I exported the required components inside modules configuration.

FreeBalanceEditPageComponent calls api method to get info by Id.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.income$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
    this.service.getIncomeFullInfo(params.get('id')))
);
```

}

So, my problem is, when user goes to "appdomain/#/onboarding/greeting" for some reason the app wants to render FreeBalanceEditPageComponent. I made this conclusion, because in browser's network tab
I see the call *"api/getIncomeFullInfo?id=greeting"* (which gives me an error)

Here are my configurations.

**app-routing.module**

```
  {
    path: 'onboarding',
    loadChildren: () => import('./onboarding/onboarding.module').then(mod => mod.OnboardingModule),
    canLoad: [SecurityGuard, OnboardingGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(mod => mod.DashboardModule),
    canActivate: [SecurityGuard, DashboardGuard],
    canLoad: [SecurityGuard, DashboardGuard],
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }];
```

**onboarding-routing.module**

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: OnboardingComponent,
    canActivate: [SecurityGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        canActivateChild: [SecurityGuard],
        children: [
          {path: 'greeting', component: OnboardingGreetingComponent},
          {path: 'freebalance', component: FreeBalanceComponent},
          {path: 'passive', component: PassiveIncomeComponent},
          {path: 'strategies', component: StrategiesComponent},
          {path: 'targets', component: TargetsComponent},
          {path: 'finish', component: FinishComponent},
          {path: 'profile', component: OnbProfileComponent},
          {
            path: 'object',
            component: OnbObjectWrapperComponent,
            canLoad: [SecurityGuard, OnboardingGuard],
            children: [
              {path: 'incomesCreation', component: OnbIncomesCreationComponent},
              {path: 'budgetCreation', component: OnbBudgetCreationComponent},
              {path: 'editIncomes/:id', component: OnbIncomesEditComponent},
              {path: 'regularExpenseCreation', component: OnbRegularExpenseCreationComponent},
              {path: 'createPlannedExpense', component: OnbPlannedExpenseCreationComponent},
              {path: 'createGoal', component: OnbGoalCreationComponent},
              {path: 'chooseGoal', component: OnbChooseGoalTypeComponent},
              {path: 'editGoal/:id', component: CreatedGoalFullComponent},
              {path: 'editExpense/:id', component: CreatedExpenseFullInfoComponent}
            ],
          },
          {path: '', component: OnboardingGreetingComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**dashboard-routing.module**

```
   {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [SecurityGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        canActivateChild: [SecurityGuard, DashboardGuard],
        children: [
          {path: 'timeline', component: TimelineComponent},
          {path: 'calendar', component: CalendarComponent},
          {
            path: 'situation',
            loadChildren: () => import('../situation/situation.module').then(mod => mod.SituationModule),
            canActivate: [SecurityGuard, DashboardGuard],
            canLoad: [SecurityGuard, DashboardGuard],
            pathMatch: 'full'
          },
          {
            path: 'expenses',
            loadChildren: () => import('../expenses/expenses.module').then(mod => mod.ExpensesModule),
            canActivate: [SecurityGuard, DashboardGuard],
            canLoad: [SecurityGuard, DashboardGuard],
          },
          {
            path: 'incomes',
            loadChildren: () => import('../incomes/incomes.module').then(mod => mod.IncomesModule),
            canActivate: [SecurityGuard, DashboardGuard],
            canLoad: [SecurityGuard, DashboardGuard],
          },
          {
            path: 'profile',
            loadChildren: () => import('../profile/profile.module').then(mod => mod.ProfileModule),
            canActivate: [SecurityGuard],
            canLoad: [SecurityGuard],
          },
          {path: '', component: TimelineComponent}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**incomes-routing.module**

```
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [SecurityGuard],
    canLoad: [SecurityGuard],
    component: IncomesOutletComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'create',
        component: IncomesCreationComponent,
        canActivateChild: [SecurityGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'edit',
        component: IncomeEditPageComponent,
        canActivateChild: [SecurityGuard],
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'edit/:id',
        component: IncomeEditPageComponent,
        canActivateChild: [SecurityGuard]
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: FreeBalanceEditPageComponent,
        canActivateChild: [SecurityGuard],
      }
    ]
  }];
```

Comment: You have a typo error on your `"and routing for these modules:"` part with `expneses`.

Comment: @Marco Thanks for the note, but it is not the issue. My problem is that when I call /onboarding/greeting it thinks that I want to render FreeBalanceEditPageComponent, which declared in another module. but I want to render that compnent only when the path is appdomain/incomes/1234

Comment: I don't understand what it's happening. You might try to use Angury which is a free browser's extension to debug https://augury.rangle.io/ . There is a routing fonctionnality that can help.